# How precisely does a star collapse into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I think we all heard general statements like "once big enough star burns out there is nothing to prevent the gravitational collapse ending in a black hole". But I can't remember even seeing the process described precisely.

Here's the deal: at first there is a nice object, a star. Stars can be nicely modeled by general relativity, nuclear physics and statistical physics combined and very much is known about these models and it can be observed whether they agree with things like light and neutrino fluxes, surface temperature and probably also lot of other stuff I know nothing about.

After the collapse we are left with another nice object, a black hole. We know that [black holes have no hair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).

The question is: what happens in-between? More precisely, between the time when all of the nuclear material has been burned out (and if possible ignore effects like reheating of the star after big enough compression) and the time where there is nothing more than just a black hole.

> - Give a description of what happens during the collapse?
> - How does the star "lose its hair"?
> - Can the actual collapse be solved analytically?
> - At what point is singularity created?

**Update:** *I don't want to know what an outside observer will see. Instead, I'd like to find out what an individual part of the dead star will "feel" when a black hole is about to form near it. In other words, I want a complete solution (ideally analytical, but numerical would be also completely fine)*

Feel free to assume anything that makes your life easier. Spherical symmetry is definitely fine. Also, if for any reason the questions don't make sense (like Cauchy problem is ill-defined in the presence of the singularity) feel free to interpret them in a way that make them sensible (e.g. assume that black hole is built from D-branes).

---

Also, I have a feeling that what I intended as a simple question at first ended up being pretty complex. If you think it should be split into smaller (and therefore more manageable and answerable) parts, let me know.

Comment: I take it this is *not* a question that should be answered in terms of the layered burnout of the core of a large star because you are interested in what happens after the collapse of the electron degenerate core, the free-fall of the outer layers and the big rebound? I think that subsequent events are still ill-understood, especially as there are complicated angular-momentum driven goings on.

Comment: @dmckee: indeed, I should have made it clear (will do) that I am not interested in the complete life of the star; just the very last part before becoming a black hole.

Comment: Ok, the general case can't be solved analytically. I think that there is an analytic solution only for dust. The problem of the formation of the horizon is interesting, since you have things like apparent horizons forming. I don't think you can tell much about the singularity. The general idea is that the hairs are radiated away with gravitational waves in the general case, but there are no hairs in the case of spherical collapse. There is some work of Nikos Stergioulas on the subject. I'll find the paper and I'll post it. If I'm up to it I'll try to turn that answer in to a real post.

Comment: @Vagelford: The dust solution would also be fine, if that's all that can be solved. As I said, feel free to interpret questions in any way that makes your life easier. I hope you can find that reference.

Comment: I don't think the question is necessarily too complex, so much as its still an active research question.  Generating astrophysically realistic gravitational waveforms for collapsing stars is one of the major tasks that the theoretical researchers working on LIGO have, for example.  It might be helpful if you said what part of the collapse you were most interested in, though--the way the multipole moments of the star radiate away?  the formation of the horizon?  Or the formation of the singularity?  Does MathJax support pstricks?  I could draw a P-C diagram of the O-S spacetime...

Comment: @Jerry: thank you for your detailed comment! Indeed, I was not really aware that this process was an active area of research. The statement about collapse of generic star into a black hole is so common (and usually just taken for granted) that I assumed that much more is known.

Comment: @Jerry: as for my interests... I think formation of singularity itself (or if that is too much to ask then formation of horizons) and the second one would be, how much is BH with matter under horizon (e.g. matter that just crossed the horizon and is still falling into singularity) different from a vacuum BH solution that assumes no matter at all. I think the two cases must be pretty different, given that there was enough matter to form BH in the first place.

Comment: @Jerry: as for the pstricks... I have no idea. But it would surely be great if any kind of vector graphics were supported (e.g. MetaPost). I'll try to find out more about this later, or perhaps ask question at meta.SO.

Comment: Ok, these are the references, http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403029
http://people.sissa.it/~rezzolla/Whisky/WhiskyI/
http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0501080
The second link has at the bottom two videos. The first is about the collapse. The second shows the formation of the horizon. The transparent white surface is the apparent horizon and the second white surface that comes from the interior is the true horizon.

Comment: Sorry, it is the other way around. The transparent surface is the event horizon and the white surface is the apparent horizon. As the video shows, the apparent horizon forms at the interior of the event horizon and expands until it comes in contact with the event horizon.

Comment: In spherical symmetry, there is actually no difference between a BH with matter under horizon and a pure BH.  In fact, there is no difference between the exterior of ANY spherically symmetric matter distribution and a BH.  It's a little tricker outside of spherical symmetry, but perturbative GR tells you that things inside the horizon can't have contact with things outside the horizon, and that includes gravitational signals, too.

Comment: @Jerry, I realize that the interior of the BH is causally disconnected from the exterior. But I was asking something a little different. Namely, classical BH assumes that the space-time is vacuum everywhere. So these solutions definitely can't describe what happens to matter that falls under the horizon (as that matter could perturb the space-time also under the horizon) with the only exception of test particles (which don't perturb the space-time by assumption). Right? Or is there a mistake in my thinking?

Comment: If the perturbation is spherically symmetric (and the background is spherically symmetric too), then the only thing that will modify the vacuum exterior is the fact that you've perturbed the mass that distant observers will see.  There is an exact theorem that says that the exterior of any spherically symmetric body must be the Schwarzschild metric.  Much the same as the result you get in Maxwell theory when the exterior of any spherically symmetric charge distribution must have the form $k\frac{Q}{r^{2}}$.

Comment: I would expect that non-spherical matter falling in would be identifiable only by its imprint on the horizon (and by outgoing gravitational waves), also, but I don't know where a rigorous proof of this is, though.  Also, stackexchange's build of MathJax doesn't seem to support pstricks.  So no Penrose-Carter diagram

Comment: @Jerry: I am not sure why, but we are not able to understand each other. Perhaps my question doesn't make sense, but I am interested in the **interior** of the BH, not the exterior. I know these questions don't make sense from the point of view of an outside observer but I'd still like to get as complete physical picture as possible. And that includes interior.

Comment: @Jerry, as for the Penrose-Carter: that's indeed a pity. Do you think you could get a reference to the diagram somewhere? I suppose it must've been drawn by someone already. Actually, I am going to try to find it myself. ...okay, I found some [notes](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fuserweb.port.ac.uk%2F~seahras%2Fdocuments%2Fnotes%2Fnotes.pdf&rct=j&q=penrose-carter%20oppenheimer-snyder&ei=qgwJTZKZC8q08QP3_41H&usg=AFQjCNFiy69EhmHBniXXI3UZRK_q64KbLQ&sig2=qI0csO5f7QqMgktV4th7ag&cad=rja)

Comment: @Marek: yeah, the appendix to that looks pretty good.  Note how the main thing that happens is that the matter's life simply ENDS when the singularity forms.  They don't get advance notice or anything, and they dont' see a singularity form, they just observe an apparent horizon, and then end up at a central singularity.  The situation is a little trickier for a collapse to a Kerr hole, where the singularity forms a timelike surface, though.  Infalling Kerr test particles do not inexorably reach the singularity, they're just trapped in the horizon.

Comment: @Jerry: thanks for the clarification. And yeah, those notes look quite good. I'll see whether they answer all of my questions.

Comment: Anologous to other things in nature the black hole would surely form at the tiniest size and then expand. I would imagine one or more "seeds" of the black hole would be created at the densest part of the implosion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution for this problem for a dust equation of state and spherical symmetry is known as the Oppenheimer-Snyder solution. You model the interior of the distribution as a FRW universe with positive spatial curvature, zero pressure, and zero cosmological constant. You model the exterior of the solution as the Schwarzschild solution cut off at a time-dependent radius. So long as the matter distribution is dust, the thing satisfies all of the junction conditions you need. See Poisson's relativity book or MTW.

A more general solution requires numerics.  But one thing we can say for sure is that there is no need for the black hole to shed its 'hair' in the case of spherical symmetry--the radial dependence of the solution will just compress into the singularity eventually, or scatter out to infinity.  Birchoff's theorem tells us every spherically symmetric vacuum solution must be the Schwarzschild solution (perhaps with an electrostatic charge, which is technically not vacuum).  This is related to the fact that there can be no monopole radiation in relativity.

Also, the general case for this problem is very likely chaotic.  Already, if the equation of state of the matter is that of a classical, spherically symmetric, Klein-Gordon field, which is a relatively simple generalization, the system exhibits a (link is a large postscript file)[second-order phase transition](http://laplace.physics.ubc.ca/People/petryk/phd.ps), a result found by Matt Choptuik, and related to the settling of the Hawking naked singularity bet.

Comment: And I should say that, in the Oppenheimer-Snyder solution, the "big bang" joins on to the white hole singularity in the extended schwarzschild solution, while the "big crunch" joins onto the black hole singularity.

Comment: Minor comment to the answer (v4): In several of your [answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=birchof*) Mr. [Birkhoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff's_theorem_%28relativity%29) is misspelled. This could make your answers harder to find in keyword searches.

Answer (score 2):

The "hair" is lost via gravitational radiation. This is also known as quasi-normal ringdown, as the BH vibrates at different frequencies much like a drum (maybe a "gong" is better analogy). Any charge on the black hole will simple get shorted out by free charges in the surrounding plasma, on a very short time scale.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also known how and when singularity and horizon form? Or is this information too much to ask for? To try to give answer myself: to tell anything about formation of the singularity one would probably need quantum gravity? And the horizon forms as soon as there is critical amount of matter, I guess.

Comment: @Marek:  for the Oppenheimer-Snyder solution, you model the interior matter as a closed FRW model, and join on the 'big bang' sinularity to a white hole singularity, and the 'big crunch' singularity to a black hole schwarzschild singularity, and paste the spacetimes together.  So the singularity forms instantaneously at exactly the point at which the FRW observers' geodesics end.  The only warning those observers get is when they see an apparent horizon form around them.

Comment: @Jerry, yes I think I got the picture after our discussion above (which happened after I posted this comment). But thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: As somebody around here noted, it is hard to say "when" the singularity happened, because it is very much observer dependent. From an observer far from the BH (i.e., "coordinate time"), the singularity is NEVER reached. But from a free-falling observer on his way to the singularity, it is reached in roughly a light-crossing time (~10 microseconds)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to do an intuitive explanation as I do not possess the mathematical knowledge for any further analysis.

I do not think, for an outside observer, singularity would form in a definite time. Rather, when the density inside is enough for an event horizon to form, i.e., the radius is smaller than the Schwarzschild radius, a black hole is said to be formed, not its singularity though. Because, for an outside observer, time comes to a complete stop at the event horizon, and only if the event horizon gets smaller, can the region inside the initial event horizon make sense for the outside observer. So if you believe that Hawking Radiation exists, then in a finite amount of time, the black hole will slowly evaporate until it's event horizon is nothing more than a singularity, then evaporate completely.

So rather than an actual forming of a singularity at a certain time for an outside observer, the mass that is "queued up" gradually condenses into a singularity, while also evaporating via hawking radiation.

As for the losing of the hair, once the event horizon forms, the hair of the materials at the event horizon or inside are lost because there are two possible fates(actually one final ultimate fate) for a particle until the forming of the singularity that I mentioned: it will be emitted as energy due to hawking radiation, or it will be the part of the last singularity which will also evaporate due to hawking radiation.

This question is actually similar to a question that I had asked and couldn't explain what I meant very clearly.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it more clear that I am not interested in outside observers. I want to know what our equations tell us about this problem and they should describe everything, singularity included (or maybe they fail to do this; if so I want to why and where). If you need to have an observer, imagine there is one that lives inside the star. What does he experience when the black hole is about to form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda out of my depth here, but I think the balding issue can be understood in cartoon terms as an effect of the time dilation of events nearing the event horizon. From outside all the material appears to stack-up against the horizon and things appear to stop happening. If there are no dynamics there can only be static effects: i.e. electrostatics and gravitation.

Comment: Seeing that there are two answers that look at the problem from the outside I will clarify that this is not what I am interested in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to focus on what an individual part of the dead star will "feel" when it becomes a black hole, I think the "no hair" part is outside the scope of that; that's a condition only for someone outside of the hole. (See "externally observable" in that Wikipedia link on "no hair" you gave.) For someone falling with the collapsing body, whether or not it's a star, the body has "hair" all the way short of the singularity. (*At* the singularity, general relativity breaks down.) I'd say the singularity is first formed when the first chunk of matter that is below the new horizon reaches the center.

Answer (score 0):

> - Give a description of what happens during the collapse?

Firstly your assumption that first the nuclear fires burn out, and then a collapse happens afterwards is just that, an assumption. An event horizon can start at a point in empty space and expand and grow into a shell that expands outwards at the speed of light until it reaches some matter far far away. And the inside could very well still have nuclear fire burning inside for a while longer before the singularity forms.

So what does happen for sure? The matter falls in. The local inertial frames actually had to supply an outwards pressure to cause an acceleration to keep it from infalling. You stay on the surface of the earth because in a local inertial frame, a pressure is pushing on your feet, accelerating you upwards. A collapse literally feels as simple as like feeling less pressure on your feet. Like an elevator going down. That's what it feels like.

Unless you are asking about tidal forces, and those depend on the size of the black hole. Those get stronger as you go deeper. But the strength depends on how big you are. For a gas, your size is the size of an atom, so it happens at the level below where we do the fluid approximation and all the statistical mechanics.

> - How does the star "lose its hair"?

Gravitational radiation (gravitational waves) do carry some away. But the hair is from the outside. And from the outside the black hole is never finished forming.

> - Can the actual collapse be solved analytically?

Examples are in "*Simple analytical models of gravitational collapse*" by R. J. Adler, J. D. Bjorken, P. Chen, and J. S. Liu in **American Journal of Physics** 73, 1148 (2005); http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.2117187

> - At what point is singularity created?

From the outside, never. From the inside you can track each layer of the star until it reaches the singularity. For a spherically symmetric star, the creation of the singularity is not when the center layer hits the singularity, because the singularity exists like a time, not like a place or an event. For a rotating star, I'm not sure anyone has the model you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I would hazard a guess that aside from time dilation effects, in many case it is probably a slow process. If the mass of the core is marginal for forming a BH, you should initially get a neutron star. As the NS cools, accumulates more material, and/or sheds angular momentum it
can cross a threshold for collapse to a BH.

I suspect that in many SN, you get enough angular momentum, so that you get some sort of accretion disklike thing, which again must shed angular momentum before it gets small/dense enough to collapse into the BH. And even then I suspect you might have a phase where there is a smallish BH surrounded by a large heavy accretion disk, which takes its time getting swallowed up. I'm not so sure if any of that happens with ultramassive stars (i.e > 150 times a massive as the sun), these might directly collapse. But, the more common run of the mill heavystars might not take a direct collapse trajectory, but instead spend a period of time losing various forms of energy (thermal, rotational, magnetic) before they can collapse all the way. This energy loss probably results in gamma ray bursts.

Comment: Actually, a neutron star of sufficiently small mass is a stable end state.  Neutron degeneracy pressure exists even at zero Kelvin, and that's what stabilizes them.

Comment: depends what you mean by "slow process." the actual collapse is on the order of a light-crossing time, i.e. 10-20 microseconds for a 10M_sun core. the subsequent accretion of a high-density disk in a GRB could take hundreds of milliseconds, but that still sounds pretty fast to me.

Comment: No. I'm thinking that a neutron star forms, which without spin and high internal temperature is beyond the mass limit, but is still stable while it is still hot and rapidly rotating. Once it is able to shed some of this stabilizing energy it can then collapse.

Comment: @Omega : that's not how it works out.  If the star is over the mass limit, the NS state will have a lifetime of seconds.  It might be enough for the star to lose some mass from the recoil pressure wave, but not enough to slow down the collapse much at all.

Comment: I seem to recall hearing about a supernova being observed, and then a gamma ray burst being observed from the same location a couple of days later. If we assume two things (my memory is correct), and the gammaray burst is the result of blackhole formation then we have at least one case where there has been a delay. I suspect that timescales computed from spherically symmetric simulations may not be indicative of what happens in real 3dimensional geometry.

Comment: As far as I know, the GRB has to do with the fireball of the explosion of the star. On the other hand the end state of the star has to do with the mass/rotation of the core. The collapse of the core can be delayed for some time due to differential rotation, in the sense that the core could form a differentially rotating neutron star that could have mass that can't be supported by uniform rotation. So when magnetic braking stops diff. rotation, which happens really fast (I don't have in mind the time scale but if I remember correctly is small), the star collapses to a Black Hole.

Answer (score -2):

I doubt that a BH is able to form.
I think that before the boundary condition is reached some mechanism acts, for example conversion of mass into radiation, which expels the excess weight out of the system.

EDIT ADD 2015/11:
In this doc we can see why a BH will not form at all, as I said in my answer.
[New study claims black holes are mathematically impossible](http://www.geek.com/science/new-study-claims-black-holes-are-mathematically-impossible-1605320/)
[Backreaction of Hawking radiation on a gravitationally collapsing star I: Black holes?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269314006686) 2014/11

Comment: after reading Omega Centauri above comment "...observed... the gammaray burst is the result of blackhole formation..." and also Valgeford comment "...the GRB has to do with the fireball of the explosion of the star..." IMO it seems that the GRB can carry enough mass/energy away of the system preventing the limit situation.