# How does a distant observer see matters that "form" an initial black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, observers, gravitational-collapse

I did see [Can black holes form in a finite amount of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5031/) but it does not seem to discuss how a distant observer would see evolution of collapsing matters that form a black hole. Does it view these matters as disappearing under the horizon, or does it see being radiated back by Hawking radiations, with a distant observer unable to actually see matters falling into the horizon?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47669/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34816/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325320/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309990/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking the far away observer never seen the black hole forming, and after a while it will start receiving Hawking radiation, until nothing is left.
The evaporation process can be thought as starting slightly outside the horizon (at a Stretched horizon). This is pictured in the image on the left, a Penrose diagram of an evaporating black hole (remember that light travel at $45°$ degrees here)

[image: Taken from http://inspirehep.net/record/1193035/plots]

Have a look also at:

[From where (in space-time) does Hawking radiation originate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22498/from-where-in-space-time-does-hawking-radiation-originate)