# Can one observe a blackhole grow from outside its event horizon?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, spacetime, time-dilation, event-horizon

For an observer outside Black hole's event horizon nothing ever falls into the black hole .

So if the observer waits for an eternity outside a super massive blackhole feeding on gas , will the observer ever see the blackhole grow in size expanding its event horizon ?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1916/50583